# Change name of rubygems package?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have pushed a gem to rubygems and realized after the fact that I left the name as uppercase in the gemspec.

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name        = 'Pagescript' # oops
  # ...
end
```

Can I fix this and push a new version or will it create a new gem on rubygems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the case of the gem I had to yank the previous releases and push the gem again. Not ideal but better to avoid confusion down the line.